# Service layer injection is not working after i exposed service layer as webservice

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

I have one service class to do the DB operations through the DAO classes , i inject the DAO object using spring. It is working fine.

After that i exposed the same method as a webservice method using JAX-WS annotation.

After that it is not working it saying my dao object not get injected , so i am getting nullpointerexception. the way i am doing is correct or not?

My service class is

```
package com.tecnotree.upc.services.impl;

import com.tecnotree.upc.services.*;
import com.tecnotree.upc.entities.*;
import com.tecnotree.upc.dao.UpcLineOfBusinessDao;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,
            parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class UpcLineOfBusinessServiceImpl implements UpcLineOfBusinessService {
    private UpcLineOfBusinessDao upcLineOfBusinessDao;

    public void setUpcLineOfBusinessDao(
            UpcLineOfBusinessDao upcLineOfBusinessDao) {
        this.upcLineOfBusinessDao = upcLineOfBusinessDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @WebMethod
    public UpcLineOfBusinessEntity createUpcLineOfBusinessEntity(
            UpcLineOfBusinessEntity upcLineOfBusinessEntity) {
        try{
        if(upcLineOfBusinessDao!=null)
            return upcLineOfBusinessDao.create(upcLineOfBusinessEntity);
        else
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    }

}
```

My spring xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<bean id="upcDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.4.33:1521:lt33" />
    <property name="username" value="UPC_PROD" />
    <property name="password" value="UPC_PROD" />
</bean>
<bean id="upcSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="upcDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>/com/tecnotree/upc/hbmfiles/UpcLineOfBusinessEntity.hbm.xml
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="upcSessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="upcLineOfBusinessDao" class="com.tecnotree.upc.dao.impl.UpcLineOfBusinessDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="upcSessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="upcLineOfBusinessService" class="com.tecnotree.upc.services.impl.UpcLineOfBusinessServiceImpl">
    <property name="upcLineOfBusinessDao">
        <ref bean="upcLineOfBusinessDao" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: please provide some of the relevant code

Comment: you cant turn a dao into a webservice just by adding annotation, a web service must correspond to a wsdl, you should auto generate yous WS client based on a online wsdl.

Comment: You need to tell us where the null pointer exsception is being thrown, we have no way of guessing.

Comment: in this line upcLineOfBusinessDao.create(upcLineOfBusinessEntity); i am getting nullpointerexception. Anyway to solve this? Please help me

Comment: should I need to use SpringBeanAutowiringSupport class in my service layer?

Comment: Can you check for any exceptions when spring container starts up and post here ?

Comment: No i am not getting any exception while spring container starts up. My all beans are loaded successfully...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by extending the SpringBeanAutowiringSupport in my service class . Now it  is working fine . Thank you for all comments